# svscan error when installing qmail

Tags: linux, centos, email, daemontools

I'm quite new to Linux and I'm running into an issue. Searched everywhere, without finding a solution.

I tried to install qmail following [these instructions](http://raman-kumar.blogspot.nl/2013/02/qmail-installation-configuration-step.html). Before finishing and starting the service, you can perform a final check.

This is the output:

```
'! svscan /service' doesn't seem to be running
! /var/log/qmail has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail
! /var/log/qmail/qmail-smtpd has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail/qmail-smtpd
! /var/log/qmail/qmail-pop3d has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail/qmail-pop3d
! /var/log/qmail/qmail-send has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail/qmail-send
! /etc/tcp.smtp is missing
...try: echo '127.:allow,RELAYCLIENT=""' >>/etc/tcp.smtp
! /etc/tcp.smtp.cdb is missing
...try: /var/qmail/bin/qmailctl cdb
! Alias for root is missing
...try: echo me >/var/qmail/alias/.qmail-root
! Alias for postmaster is missing
...try: echo me >/var/qmail/alias/.qmail-postmaster
! Alias for mailer-daemon is missing
...try: echo me >/var/qmail/alias/.qmail-mailer-daemon
```

I guess my first problem would be to get svscan running, but everything I try seems to fail.

My Centos version: `Linux version 2.6.32-279.14.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Nov 6 23:43:09 UTC 2012`

If you need any more information, please let me know. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

svscan is run under /etc/init.d so you should start looking there to see if it was started.
Also try

```
ps -ef|grep readproctitle
```

does the above return any errors ?

further more : 
You have wrong permissions in your /var/log/qmail directories.

Do `chmod -R 750 /var/log/qmail` to fix that.

Also you need to create the tcp.smtp file

```
echo '127.:allow,RELAYCLIENT=""' >> /etc/tcp.smtp
```

and then `qmailctl cdb`

Also you seem to not haven't set the proper aliases

```
echo root@mail.com > /var/qmail/alias/.qmail-root
echo postmaster@mail.com > /var/qmail/alias/.qmail-postmaster
echo daemon@mail.com > /var/qmail/alias/.qmail-mailer-daemon
ln -s /var/qmail/alias/.qmail-root /var/qmail/alias/.qmail-anonymous 
chmod 644 /var/qmail/alias/.qmail*
```

Lastly to be frank QMailRocks (which it seems the site you follow pretty much copies) has not been maintained in ages and ages as a guide to setup Qmail. Try and visit [qmail.jms1.net](http://qmail.jms1.net) for a bit updated info

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your repsonse.

I've searched for svscan under `/etc/init.d`, it's not there (so obviously it's not running).

Output off `ps -ef|grep readproctitle`:

```
root    1560 4013  0 11:15 pts/1    00:00:00 grep readproctitle
```

Although I followed `chmod -R 750 /var/log/qmail` and checked if permissions were set correct (and they are), the error still turns up. Don't know if I can neglect that.

I solved the other issues.

Furthermore, I found out (using your suggested link) that qmail is running and able to send messages, svscan however is not running and I still get these error messages:

```
'! svscan /service' doesn't seem to be running
! /var/log/qmail has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail
! /var/log/qmail/qmail-smtpd has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail/qmail-smtpd
! /var/log/qmail/qmail-pop3d has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail/qmail-pop3d
! /var/log/qmail/qmail-send has wrong mode, should be 750
...try: chmod 750 /var/log/qmail/qmail-send
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

For future users who stumble upon this post as i did...

## svscanboot &

This resolved my following problem.

'! svscan /service' doesn't seem to be running